# The word — dealt

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I’ve been curious as to why the word (dealt) has the letter (a) in it. If anyone has any insight on this matter or knows where I can find the prefix and or suffix of the word to find out why I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: ??? It's the past tense of "deal". Can you explain why you think the a would be dropped?

Comment: Well, I can understand why some people might think it should be dropped (cf "feel" - "felt"; "kneel" - "knelt").  But in "deal"-"dealt", "leap" - "leapt", and "lean" - "leant", the vowel is shortened wihout the spelling changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deal** /di:l/ is the word that "dealt" /dɛlt/ is derived from.

"Dealt" is the past tense and past participle.  "-t" is a suffix used to form the past tense and past participle of some (irregular) verbs.

In some of these, including "deal"/"dealt" and "mean"/"meant", the past tense form has a shorter vowel, but the double vowel ("ea") remains present in the spelling.

Comment: Apparently it's [from the Old English *dælan*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/deal), which, at some point, someone took the *æ*, separated it, and reversed the order of the vowels.  [And also to pronounce it like "ee" in "feet" rather than like "a" in "cat"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70927/how-is-%C3%A6-supposed-to-be-pronounced)